# HTML Email: What does data-upload-file-url do?

Tags: html, ajax, html-email

I'm relatively new to HTML Email Development, and I'm trying to improve my understanding of HTML Email structures by dissecting HTML Emails on "reallygoodemails.com".

On the HTML Email example located at the following address: "https://reallygoodemails.com/emails/get-across-the-finish-line/live" , there is a table tag on line "240" with the attribute/value pair: data-upload-file-url="/ajax/email-editor/file/upload".

I know it's got something to do with an ajax HTTPrequest, but what is this attribute/value pair actually doing, and should I be including it in my own HTML Email production?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi @Weis.Dime,  the `data-xxxx` attribute is used to store data on the html.

Answer (score 0):

It's likely put there by some automated process such as during the build of the email, to perhaps tell a process where to look for images to upload. This doesn't change anything on the design/look of the email itself. You don't need it.